# Como modificar a imagem que aparece no facebook quando posto o link do meu site?

Tags: php, html, facebook, html-meta-tag

Sempre que posto o link do meu site no facebook exibe uma imagem padrão que antes utilizava para este fim. Porém fiz a alteração da imagem na TAG abaixo há mais de 6 dias, só que ainda a antiga continua aparecendo. Lembrando que a nova imagem está com um novo nome e a antiga foi deletada do servidor, mas continua não sei de onde capturando a antiga.

Já teste em diversos computadores e dispositivos móveis.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.roteirodoimovel.com.br/roteiroimagemnovo.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="720">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="479">
```

Preciso muito de ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Dependendo da quantidade de acessos, o Facebook pode manter os arquivos em cache por um bom tempo.

Para forçar a atualização das informações, você deve acessar https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug e pedir para ele atualizar, digitando a URL que deseja, então clique em **Debug** e, depois, **Fetch new scrape information** (não sei se há versão em pt-br, se houver, editem, por favor).

Fazendo isso para sua URL (http://www.roteirodoimovel.com.br/) dá um **warning**:

> **og:image could not be downloaded or is too small**
>
> og:image was not defined, could not be downloaded or was not big enough. Please define a chosen image using the og:image metatag, and use an image that's at least 200x200px and is accessible from Facebook. Image 'http://www.roteirodoimovel.com.br/roteiroimagem.jpg' will be used instead. Consult http://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler for more troubleshooting tips.

Comment: Não funcionou..

Comment: @GladisonNeuzaPerosini Facebook não consegue baixar a sua imagem. Veja o warning que dá. Já vi casos em que a declaração do width e height da imagem podem causar isso. Tente remover e deixar o Facebook cuidar disso. Ou coloque um valor menor, como 200x200.

Comment: Removi as TAG´s mas o problema em warning continua.

Comment: O mesmo problema, não atualiza.